# How to use tablet-specific layout when in landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-orientation

I have defined a tablet-specific layout in the `res/layout-sw600dp` folder. Now. It loads correctly in tablet emulator and is checked and managed by code as expected.     The problem is that I cannot access this layout variant to use in mobile emulator after I check that orientation is landscape. When I type in code `R.layout.`, no hint is given as to the specific tablet layout, only one instance is given, `activity_main`. How can I use that tablet layout in the landscape orientation as well?

```
./app/src/main/res/layout-sw600dp/activity_filter.xml
./app/src/main/res/layout/activity_filter.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

The "smallest width" qualifier doesn't care about device orientation. You'll have to make a copy of your layout and put it in the `res/layout-land/` directory if you want that same layout on phones in landscape.

If you don't want to have two exact duplicate layouts (one in `sw600dp` and one in `land`), you can look into using a resource alias: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseAliasFilters